# Overloading the [] operator of a template class, get and set, in c++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, set, square-bracket

Basically, I'm trying to make template map/dictionary class for c++ (I know this have already been done, assume I'm masochistic).

I started up, writing this skeleton:

```
#pragma once
template <class T>
class AssArray
{
    int _size;
    int _position;

public:
    AssArray(int size);
    ~AssArray(void);

    const T& operator [](char* b) const;
    T& operator [](char* b) const;
        //I read this should be done sth like this when researching, though an explanation would be nice.
};
```

Now, I need to be able to get (T=AssArray["llama"]), set (AssArray["llama"]= T) and override (AssArray["llama"]= newT).

Doing this is pretty straight forward, just loop it through etc, the real problem here is the operators;

if I use AssArray["llama"]= T, how am I supposed to get the value of T into the operator overloading-function?

I've only found explanations describing the solutions briefly, and can not really follow.
Please enlighten me.

Comment: Your question is quite difficult to understand. What does "loop it through" mean? You don't need to do anything to make this work other than fix the `operator[]` that returns a `T&` - just remove the `const` from the end of the function declaration.

Comment: A llama (*Lama glama*) is not an ass (*E. africanus asinus*).

Comment: @Jupiter: I've rejected your edit.  It is a valid correction to the code, but it is not the code the OP is asking about.  Instead, the OP should be informed of the invalidity, which I will do now.  @user1670056: If you want your overloaded operator to be able to accept string literals, as in `ass_array["llama"] = x;`, you need to make the parameter of type `char const*`, not `char*`.

Comment: The looping through it is just that you need to make sure that the key you are going to use doesn't already exist in the AssArray.

I have it mostly figured out, now I'm just dealing with some linker errors *shudder*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is correct your signatures like so:

```
const T& operator [](char* b) const;
T& operator [](char* b);
```

I've removed the `const` qualifier from the second operator.

> if I use `AssArray["llama"]=T`, how am I supposed to get the value of T into the operator overloading-function?

You don't. You just return a reference to where the new value should be stored, and the compiler will take care of the rest. If `"llama"` does not exist in the array, you need to create an entry for it, and return a reference to that entry.

Answer (score 0):

Since the operator[] returns a reference to T if you want to say assArray["str"] = T the type T has to know what to do with the operator=. If T does not have the operator= overloaded you have to overload the operator= in type T.

operator[] has nothing to do with assignments. It should just return the element at the given index.